# Changing a question between active and passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

How do I say

> Did you fed my fish?

in the passive voice?

How do I ask

> What's drawn?

in the active voice

Answer (score 1):

Take the first question. It should be "Did you feed my fish."

To help you think about this, it may be easier to think of the statement "You fed my fish". Which could be expressed as "My fish were fed (by you)". If you make that a question you would get "Were my fish fed?"

The second is odd, since the present tense would not normally be used. But again, change to a statement: "What is drawn?" -> "Something is drawn (by you)" -> "You draw something" -> "What do you draw?"

Remember: don't use the passive unless you have a good reason for it. For example, you might use "Were my fish fed" if you don't want to mention the person who may have fed the fish, which might be polite.